# Feed's Regex find replace problem

Tags: feeds

Hello Drupal community,

I'm finding some issues in a tamper used in feed's module. I want spaces to be deleted in a field that contains numbers. Something that changes "00 00 00 00 00" into "0000000000".
I've tried the following :

```
    Regex to find : #(\d{2})[ ](\d{2})[ ](\d{2})[ ](\d{2})[ ](\d{2})#
    Replacement pattern : $1$2$3$4$5
```

[image]

Note that the expression was validated in https://regex101.com/ :
[image]

But it doesn't seem to work.
Anyone please ?

Comment: try `str_replace(" ", "", $string);` or `preg_replace("/ +/", "", $string);`

Comment: @BipinK Actually, i'm not custom coding it. It's part of feed's tamper module. I just added the imagine to illustrate the problem. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @IsmaH No matter if you are custom coding it or not - it is good idea to test if your regexp is valid in the first place. At the moment I see nothing like that in your question. See [here](https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html) if you don't have easy access to php-enabled shell.

Comment: @Mołot I've already tested the pattern in https://regex101.com/ and it's working. I will change my post accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is something like this

```
#(\d{2})\s+#
```

and then replace with $1

then if you need to limit it, use the limit field.

Its better to try and match the pattern thank the whole string- that one matches 2 numbers, followed by at least one space, and replaces it with the captured number (in brackets) - so it'll match the whole thing.

you could add a positive look ahead (?\d) to make sure it matches 2 numbers then space followed by a number, but testing the above worked

Answer (score 1):

Try giving **Limit number of replacements**  value as `-1` This will solve your issue.

Comment: Not working :( :( Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution to this exact issue, but a troubleshooting guide:

What was helpful to me was to dpm the module's parameters and variables.  In this file: \sites\all\modules\feeds_tamper\plugins\find_replace_regex.inc - modify this code to insert dpm() functions.  (you'll need the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module for this)

```
function feeds_tamper_find_replace_regex_callback($result, $item_key, $element_key, &$field, $settings, $source) {
  dpm($field);
  $field = preg_replace($settings['find'], $settings['replace'], $field, $settings['real_limit']);
  dpm($field);
}
```

Then go to your importer page /import and run the import you've created.

Regex101 doesn't emulate php exactly from my personal experience.  My tests would return "" in conflict with Regex101.  For a quick php-test use: http://phptester.net/

like this:

```
$string = 'echoMyString';
$regex = '/(echo)(MyString)/';
$replace = '$2';

echo preg_replace($regex, $replace, $string, '-1');

[Output:] MyString
```

This procedure helped me troubleshoot why my regex wasn't working for [Feeds Tamper Importer](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper_importer)